# uncaught exception : -{WebDataSource indexof:]: unrecognized selector while using framework

Tags: iphone, ios, tabbar, uitabbaritem

```
 - (void)ItemPressed:(id)sender {
    NSInteger index = [self.tabBarItems indexOfObject:sender];
    BOOL shouldSelect = [self delegatedDecisionIfWeShouldSelectViewController:[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index] atIndex:index];

    if (shouldSelect) {
        if (index != self.selectedIndex) {
            self.selectedIndex = index;
        } else {
            if ([self.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
                UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.selectedViewController;

                [navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hi I am Created tabbarcontroller framework all **working fine using source**  **but created framework getting error while selecting one index to another**

**`-{WebDataSource indexof:]:  unrecognized selector instance`**
 i got the above error.

any thoughts?

i declared tabbar items like below

```
vc1 = [[webviewname alloc] initUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]];
    vc2 = [[webviewname  alloc] initUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.yahoo.com"]];

    vc1.O_tabBarItem = [OTabBarItem itemWithTitle:@"index" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"index"]];
    vc2.O_tabBarItem = [OTabBarItem itemWithTitle:@"index" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"index"]];


    vc1.delegate=self;
    vc2.delegate=self;

    NSArray *vControl = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1,vc2,nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you expected `self.tabBarItems` to be an `NSArray` object. But here, the object refers some other instance, say instance of `WebDataSource`.

Is it possible to show, how you have declared and populated the array `tabBarItems` ?

Comment: Hi added the source please check it

Comment: But, where you have added the action for the button?